# Does Oracle optimize database while you use?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-xe

I have a 10gb database, that the queries were running very fast on Oracle XE.

I exported this db with `expdp` and imported on a new server Oracle 12c (hardware better than original, much more RAM and CPU) with `impdp` and now the queries are being slow.

I think Oracle created some internal optimisation based on queries I frequently do, and now that the Database is imported, he lost all this optimisations. This is just my theory.

Anyone knows if Oracle optimize database while you use? If yes, how do I accelerate this process on a recently imported schema.

Edit: I monitored v$sql_monitor and there was just one problem I fixed with a new index. But queries still are slow.

Comment: Have you gathered statistics?

Comment: Yes, looked in v$sql_monitor and no problem there.

Comment: Do you have an example query with the old and new explain?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you have indexes that are unusable. Check and see if you have unusable indexes. If you do, then you need to rebuild them.

```
SELECT owner, status, COUNT(*) FROM dba_indexes GROUP BY owner, status ORDER BY 1,2;
```